# XCode does not build Unity3D Project: lib not found

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, linker-errors

I have Unity3D project and I built it for iOS. If I run it using XCode's simulator it works fine. But if I want to compile it for "iOS Device" or for a physical device connected to my Mac, I get lots of errors and as a result I can't create an Archive.
For a testing purpose, I even created an empty Unity3D project, built it for iOS and still get the same errors, although this project does absolutely nothing.
The errors are the following:

> ld: library not found for -liPhone-lib
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

And these are the settings I use:

- Architectures: armv7, armv7s, arm64  (also tried removing arm64 without any positive result)
- Base SDK: iOS 7.1
- Build active: no
- Supported platform: iOS
- Valid arch:  armv7, armv7s, arm64

I use XCode 5.1.1 and Unity 4.5.1 (previously even tried 4.3.2)

**How can I build the project and create the Archive?**

Comment: I don't think this specifically will solve your issue, but Unity's `iPhone-lib` is currently only built for `armv7`, not `armv7s` nor `arm64`.  That is, your **Architectures** setting must be set to **only `armv7`** to build for device.  Valid Architectures is best left at the iOS Default (when viewing Levels of settings, not Combined).

Answer (score 5):

I've run into the same issue some time ago and it was fixed by replacing quotes under library search path:

replace

```
"$(SRCROOT)/Libraries"
```

with

```
$(SRCROOT)/Libraries
```

more: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/538363/error-when-i-updated-to-xcode-5-to-get-import-to-i.html